# Effects of Mutable objects in an ObjectStream

Tags: java, stream, mutable

I am attempting to send packets between a client and a server using an ObjectInputStream and an ObjectOutputStream, obtained from a Socket. However I was getting some weird results in trying to send an object down the stream, my class structure looks somewhat as follows:

```
public class Packet {
  public Foo foo;
}

public class Foo {
  public float hp = 100;
  public double mass = 10;
  public void takeDamage(float dmg) {
    hp -= dmg;
    Packet p = new Packet();
    p.foo = this;
    //code to send packet to server
  }
}
```

However I have found that the server receives a different value of Foo when it arrives - mass is always received properly however hp, which can be changing up to 50 times a second, is not received properly (it usually is received to be around 97, regardless of the actual hp of the original object). I have checked the value of hp just before sending the packet and as soon as it arrives and it appears to just randomly be changed, but I think it may be due to the fact that p.foo is a pointer, as when I instead instead make a deep-copy:

```
p.foo = new Foo();
p.foo.hp = hp;
p.foo.mass = mass;
```

the code appears to send through the hp perfectly fine, so is it the case that Streams must be passed objects which are not mutated? And is there any good way to enforce this in java?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your entire code. Did you extend `Serializable` for `Foo`? What about `Cloneable`? Did you implement `hashCode`?

Comment: I extended Serializable, but not Cloneable or a hashCode.

Comment: @HarrisonHarris Did my answer help or at least explain things?

Comment: @Lothar yes, I'm just calling `reset()` after each write now in order to keep the cache clear, I might look into `writeUnshared()` if it's too slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I write about `ObjectOutpuStream` is also happening in `ObjectInputStream`.

`ObjectOutputStream` caches previously serialized data to just send a reference instead of the whole data if the same instance is serialized again. This makes it possible to serialize circular data structures without ending up in an infinite loop. I suppose it's because of this why you receive a different value (most likely the first value ever serialized) instead of the current one.

For the same reason you will sooner or later run into an `OutOfMemoryError` because the internal cache of the `ObjectOutputStream` will become bigger and bigger (there is no `reset` you can call).

So I suppose that you change your implementation either by using something different than an `ObjectOutputStream` or you instantiate a new `ObjectOutputStream` (you need to do that on the receiving side as well) after sending something.

Comment: “there is no `reset` you can call”—you mean except for [this `reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset--) you can call? Besides that, you can also use [`writeUnshared`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared-java.lang.Object-) to write a particular object like a copy without the need to flush the entire cache.

Comment: @Holger Hm I'm quite sure these methods didn't exist when I was running into a similar problem (more than 10 years ago, though)

Comment: Well, `writeUnshared` was added in 1.4. The `reset()` method, however, [is there from the beginning](https://web.archive.org/web/19990224161618/http://java.sun.com:80/products/jdk/1.1/docs/api/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.html#ObjectOutputStream(java.io.OutputStream))…